# How can I improve/reduce this piece of Java code

Tags: java, performance, optimization

I had a task and I completed it: The objective was to create a method with 2 arguments:
1. the number to count, and 2. how many char/numbers is the total result.

Result: Let's say that "number" is 5, so it will count: 
01234**5**43210 
BUT it will also add spaces to the sides to complete the 2nd requirement "largo", so if long is 15, the result would be 
"  01234543210  " with 2 spaces to each side.
So i wrote this piece of code, but other coder told me that he used half the lines I did.

There were many assumptions in the code, like the fact that largo is > than number or that if number is an odd number, largo is odd too.

So my question would be, can this code be reduced (refactored?)
[I just have one month in my java path so be hard but understanding XD)

```
public static void counter(int number, int largo) {
    int numberFull=(number*2)+1;
    int spaceFull=largo-numberFull;
    int space=spaceFull/2;
    for (int a=1;a<=space;++a)
        {System.out.print(" ");}
    for (int x=0;x<=number;x++)
        {System.out.print(x);}
    for (int y=number-1;y>=0;y--)
        {System.out.print(y);}
    for (int b=1;b<=space;++b)
        {System.out.print(" ");}
}
```

Comment: `long` is a reserved keyword

Comment: There is a 50% chance of being off-by-one regarding the number of spaces, i.e. in 50% of all cases, you need a different number of spaces at the end of the output than on the beginning.

Comment: You'd be better off asking this in Code Review.

Comment: @jsheeran ...after fixing the functional issues.

Comment: the original 2nd argument was "largo" but i put long here because of the meaning, forgot about the reserved word limitation.

Comment: @FernandoGonzales-Vigil You can use the word `length`.

Comment: You can assume the method parameter length is a positive odd integer and is always greater than or equal the length of the digit sequence to be printed. You can also assume that the method parameter number can only take values from 0 to 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
public static void counter(int number, int largo) {
    int space = (largo - (number * 2) - 1) / 2;
    String left = "0123456789".substring(0, number);
    String right = new StringBuilder(left).reverse().toString();
    String spaces = space > 0 ? String.format("%" + space + "s", "") : "";
    System.out.print(spaces + left + number + right + spaces);
}
```

`number` must be from 0 to 9.

Comment: I havent used Stringbuilder before.  Nice one! I'l take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I find your code fine (apart from the formating).
For your (mathematical) entertainment;

```
int spaces = largo - (2*n + 1);
print("          ".substring(0, spaces/2));
long x = pow(111111111L % pow(10, n), 2);
if (x != 0) print(0);
print(x);
if (x != 0) print(0);
print("          ".substring(0, spaces - spaces/2));
// Or: printf("%" + (spaces - spaces/2) + "s", "");
```

I do not find this solution "nicer" - it has more restrictions.
But it utilizes 111...111^2 == 123....321.
It does away with for-loops.

Comment: Wow! Sorry i didnt pick your answer but its too heavy on math for my taste, and I learned a bit more from the other one.